# How do I search through local variables in Google Chrome Console?

Tags: google-chrome

I set a breakpoint within a function. Now, I want to search through the names of local variables for one named `foo`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried just searching for `foo`, or `foo ` or ` foo`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934787/view-list-of-all-javascript-variables-in-google-chrome-console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the scripts section, pause, and refresh. Then look in the scope variables section.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934787/view-list-of-all-javascript-variables-in-google-chrome-console

Answer (score 1):

"Waldo" should do the trick for you:

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/waldo-search-the-javascript-runtime-in-under-1-kb/

Comment: Please add more detail than just a link.